# Массивы в PHP: не корректная работа конструкции Array

Tags: php, массивы

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
$kilometri=array(
'такс'=> 200);
$x=var_dump($kilometri);
echo "в одном сантиметре содержится ($x) а в одном километре содержится";
```

Вопрос почему в строке echo он не выводит `"'такс'=>200"`, а выводит либо просто "()", либо если я меня на `$x` на `$kilometri` он выводит `"Array"`?

Comment: `$x=var_export($kilometri, true);` А вообще перед использованием функций необходимо ознакомиться с их документацией, иначе как вы можете узнать, что эта функция не форматирует ваш диск? Документация по [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php): *Выводит информацию о переменной*, по [var_export](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php): *Выводит в браузер или возвращает интерпретируемое строковое представление переменной* (см. примеры использования в документации)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете ассоциативные массивы, чтобы вывести значение (в примере ниже это 1000) придется задействовать ключ (в примере ниже это 'метр')

```
<?php
$kilometr = array( 'метр' => 1000 );
echo "в одном километре содержится {$kilometr['метр']} метров";
```

При попытке вывода переменной содержащей массив `$kilometr` без уточнения ключа, будет осуществлена попытка привести его к строке, и вам будет выведено `"Array()"`.

Comment: спасибооо _)))))))